# Programmatically Determine Java Session Timeout

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

Is there any way for a java servlet/jsp to determine the webserver's session timeout (in seconds, minutes, etc...)? I tried looking in the HttpSession and System API, but didn't see any property for determining the webserver's session timeout. I know that this value is set in web.xml, but I am designing a java library which needs to determine this through code.

Note: I am designing for a generic webserver and cannot rely on vendor specific extensions.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[`HttpSession.getMaxInactiveInterval`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpSession.html#getMaxInactiveInterval()) provides this value

> int getMaxInactiveInterval()
>
> Returns the maximum time interval, in seconds, that the servlet container will keep this session open between client accesses. After
>   this interval, the servlet container will invalidate the session. The
>   maximum time interval can be set with the setMaxInactiveInterval
>   method.
>
> A return value of zero or less indicates that the session will never timeout.
>
> Returns:
>   an integer specifying the number of seconds this session remains open between client requests

Answer (score 6):

In a Servlet use:

```
int timeoutInSeconds = request.getSession().getMaxInactiveInterval();
```

In a JSP use:

```
<p>Timeout in seconds: ${pageContext.session.maxInactiveInterval}</p>
```

Answer (score 4):

The session's timeout is determined by idle time so there is no way to know when it will timeout.

However, you can calculate the next possible timeout assuming session is not being accessed,

```
Date expiry = new Date(session.getLastAccessedTime() + session.getMaxInactiveInterval()*1000);
```

Answer (score 1):

This is the code to get the time out value:

```
<%= session.getMaxInactiveInterval() %>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can call [getMaxInactiveInterval](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpSession.html#getMaxInactiveInterval()) on your session object.